# How do I replace text, using Pseudo CSS, in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently working on a WordPress ecommerce website, where the chosen shopping platform is WooCommerce.

In the header, I have a 'Shopping Cart' area, where visitors are able to select the text and view what is in their 'Shopping Cart'.  I wanted to remove 'Shopping Cart' and replace this text entry with 'Basket'.

To achieve this, I used CSS.

Here are my codes:

**Markup:**

```
<span class="icon icon-shopping"></span>
    <span class="cart-right">
        <span class="remove-shopping-cart">Shopping cart</span>
            <span class="quantity-items">
                0 items - <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>0.00</span>                            
            </span>
    </span>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*Removes Shopping Cart*/
.remove-shopping-cart {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
/*Replace Shopping Cart with 'Shopping Basket.'*/
.remove-shopping-cart:after {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: "Basket";
}
```

The above coding, works fine in Google Chrome.  When I visit the website using Internet Explorer, there is just a blank space where 'Shopping Cart'/'Basket' should be.

Any reason for this and is there a way to resolve this?

**Added Information:**

After further inspection, using Internet Explorer, I noticed that my Pseudo CSS is crossed out/deselected in Internet Explorer, unlike in Google Chrome.  I am assuming this is the issue.  Does Internet Explorer treat Psuedo CSS differently to how Google Chrome treats such CSS?

Think I have seen the issue.  When I remove `visibility: hidden;` both 'Shopping Cart' and 'Basket' appears in Internet Explorer.  I just need to show 'Basket' and not 'Shopping Cart'.

Comment: Add `display:block`, `width` and `height` in `.remove-shopping-cart:after`

Comment: ...why not just change the word "Shopping Cart" to the word "Basket"?

Comment: @Rahul Dev I have just tried this and it does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @hypern00b 'Shopping Cart' is called from within WooCommerce rather than myself having typed it.  I am not hugely familiar with the `.pot` language files at present, so want to limit the change to CSS only for now.

Comment: @Craig You are performing simple css stuffs, It doesn't have to do anything with woocommerce or wordpress. It works fine on jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/eu8x5q6f/) . So, something else is blocking.

Comment: @RahulDev I have just figured that when I remove `visibility: hidden;`, both 'Shopping Cart' and 'Basket' appear in Internet Explorer.  They overlap one and other.  Any ideas on how I can prevent the 'Shopping Cart' from appearing?

Comment: The UK English version of WordPress automatically makes WooCommerce use "Basket" instead of "Cart". Change your language in the WP's General Settings and see if that makes the difference!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Peter.  I have managed to resolve my issue, as per my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, turns out to be of my own doing.

I had created the following directory:

> wp-content > themes > theme-name > inc > functions > woocommerce.php

With `woocommerce.php` detailing a series of functions to be included within the website's header.

I had created this a long time ago, so simply overlooked this directory.  It didn't come to mind, that this could be causing the issue, especially since my Pseudo CSS was working in all browsers except for Internet Explorer.

In the end, all I had to do was modify the original 'Shopping Cart' reference to 'Basket', within the `woocommerce.php` file, then delete the CSS I created (as per my question), and problem resolved.

Lesson learnt!

Still not sure why Google Chrome recognised my make shift CSS whilst Internet Explorer did not, though.

Comment: As a side note, my Pseudo CSS works absolutely fine.  It was just 'blocked' by my `woocommerce.php` file.  Thought I would get that out there, in case someone was looking on how to change content via Pseudo CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to target the element with JavaScript and change the "innerHTML"?

It would be something like:

```
<html>
<span class="icon icon-shopping"></span>
<span class="cart-right">
    <span id="changeCartToBasket">Shopping cart</span>
        <span class="quantity-items">
            0 items - <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>0.00</span>                            
        </span>
</span>    
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("changeCartToBasket").innerHTML = "Basket";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Not sure if something is blocking this but this suggestion does not seem to work.

Comment: @Craig Maybe check out https://raison.co/change-woocommerce-cart-basket/. 

That looks like it would be helpful to you? Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the resource @hypern00b.  I have resolved my issue, as per my answer now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine with ie

```
<span class="icon icon-shopping"></span>
<span class="cart-right">
    <span class="remove-shopping-cart">Shopping cart</span>
        <span class="quantity-items">
            0 items - <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>0.00</span>                            
        </span>
</span>

<style>
    .remove-shopping-cart {
        position: relative;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-indent: -999999px;
    }

    .remove-shopping-cart:after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        content: "Basket";
        line-height: 20px;
        text-indent: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, with the CSS.  Turns out my CSS was perfectly fine.  It was just being 'blocked' by one of my function files.  Namely, `woocommerce.php`.  I have provided further detail in my answer.  Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try jQuery method:**

```
$('.remove-shopping-cart').html($('.remove-shopping-cart').html().replace('Shopping cart','Basket'));
```

It would help to do easier way better than CSS way.

```js
$('.remove-shopping-cart').html($('.remove-shopping-cart').html().replace('Shopping cart','Basket'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="icon icon-shopping"></span>
     <span class="cart-right">
         <span class="remove-shopping-cart">Shopping cart</span>
             <span class="quantity-items">
                 0 items - <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&pound;</span>0.00</span>                            
             </span>
     </span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight.  I have resolved my issue now, as per my answer. :-)